# How to know what input method is currently used with fcitx from commandline

Tags: fcitx

Is there any way to know what input method is used with fcitx?

I checked `fcitx-remote` and other related command and goolge it, but it seems there is no way to check the current input method.

I'd like to deactivate japanese ime only it is activated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fcitx-diagnose` is too slow to use this purpose.

Comment: There is a way, sort of, via dbus. I used to have a script for switching input method for sogou pinyin, which uses fcitx. That's been a while ago, when I still used Ubuntu 16.04.